# When selecting UIViewController in UITabBarController frame of view changes

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'am having for my knowledge a strange problem. The thing is that frame of UIVIewController's view changes when is beeing displayed for the first time in UITabBarController.

I'll try to describe my architecture.
I have a class that is subclass of UITabController. Inside this class i create 3 UIViewController (A,B,C) and than put them to viewControllers array of UITabBarController.
selectedIndex of UITabBarController is set to 0 so A is the first one dislayed. Everthing renders normaly in view A. But when i switch to second view B or third view C every subview frame is somehow broken. Sizes and positions are changed.

i NSLog the frames of UIViewControllers (A, B, C) before adding them to the viewControllers array of UITabBarController and the result is (0,20,320,460). At the moment they are displayed, their frame changes to (0,0,320,411). But ViewControlles A still renders OK. Other two not:S

Answer (score 2):

Would have to see some code to know exactly what the problem is but in the meantime what you should do is setup the subviews int the viewWillAppear method of your viewController and use a BOOL to make sure they are only ever setup once (not every time the viewWillAppear method is called). This should make sure the subviews match the correct framing.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
if (!viewWasAlreadySetUpBOOL) {
//setup all the views
viewWasAlreadySetUpBOOL = YES;
}
}
```

Comment: Thx, but i don't think this solves my problem. I setup subviews of UIViewController only once before adding it to the viewControllers array of UITabBarController. i don't se viewWillAppear method at all.

Comment: I know. Use the -(void)viewWillAppear method as I described and see what happens. It will only setup the views once for each viewController (thats what the bool is for). I've had a similar issue in the past and this worked.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Ok, i will try and let you know. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense that your frame height could change after adding the views to the tabBar array.  The height of the standard tabBar is 49px, which is the difference in the height values you are seeing in your logs.  This makes sense, since each view is adjusted to fit the available screen size, minus the size of the tabBar.

How are you setting up your views, programmatically or IB? What sizes are you using?  If you are setting up your frames, either programmatically or through IB, but not taking into consideration the offset from the tabBar, it could throw off where your views are being placed.  It would help to see some code, but without any, I'd suggest checking how you adjusted your frames for the tab Bar.